# Index.html not accessed when opening website

Tags: html, web, redirect, hosting

I have a website, [norway-yv.epizy.com](http://norway-yv.epizy.com). I use InfinityFree to host (I just want to use the website for practise and as a fun hobby project). They use filemanager.ai to manage my files. I have a vast system of files and folders (see below), and instead of having to upload every file and every folder I have made it so that everything is in the website folder. This way, I do not need to upload everything every time I change something in my local copy of the website. I want `norway-yv.epizy.com` to redirect to `norway-yv.epizy.com/website/home.html`, and have done this trough an `index.html` file. However, it only gives error 404.

## My files

### `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index2.html

ErrorDocument 403 https://infinityfree.net/errors/403/
ErrorDocument 404 https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/
ErrorDocument 500 https://infinityfree.net/errors/500/
```

I have configured `http://norway-yv.epizy.com/website/myerrorpages/[errornum].html` as error page path in InfinityFree control panel

### `htdocs` (folder, automatically created)

#### `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>norway-yv</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=website/home.html">
    </body>
</html>
```

#### `website` (folder, manually created)

##### `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>norway-yv</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.html">
    </body>
</html>
```

##### `home.html`

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>norway-yv | home</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../files/icons/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normal.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="home.html">
                <img class="logoTop" src="files/icons/favicon.png" alt="Logo" />
            </a>
        </header>
        <h1>This is the website of norway-yv</h1>
        <p>I'm sorry for the horrible look of my website, but it is the best I can do</p>
        <h2>About me</h2>
        <p>I am a hobby developer who likes programming in Python. I am a student in Norwegian upper secondary school, year 1.<br>
            Some of my best projects can be found <a href="projects.html" >here.</a><br>
            Feel free to contact me trough GitHub.</p>
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/17496608/norway-yv" >StackOverflow</a><br>
            <a href="https://github.com/norway-yv"> GitHub (via GitHub e-mail)</a><br>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

##### `projects.html`

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>norway-yv | projects</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../files/icons/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normal.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="home.html">
                <img class="logoTop" src="files/icons/favicon.png" alt="Logo" />
            </a>
        </header>
        <h1>My projects</h1>
        <p>I have made tons more than this, mainly for scientific and mathematic purposes, but these are some of the projects I am most proud of:</p>
        <h2>kode24-calculator</h2>
        <p>An ongoing project, where I try to calculate expected wage for Norwegian developers using many different parametres.<br>
            For more information, see <a href="projects/kode24-calculator.html"> here. </a></p>
        <h2>binary-calculator</h2>
        <p>A project that sort of is finished, but still has a long way to go. Currently, it can calculate the sum of two binary numbers up to 32 bit size and output it.<br>
            For more information, see <a href="projects/binary-calculator.html"> here. </a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

## My comments in the end

I have much more than this in my website, with several other folders. I can add them to the question if that is necessary. But I hope not.
The same problems do occur when previewing (using edge showing the local version). So it's more of a problem with my files than InfinityFree.

Comment: It works for me.  I just tested.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Did you test the website or the HTML (like, did you copy into local and tried it, or did you visit the page on the www?)

Comment: I tested your website I didn't try to copy your code

Comment: When I go to http://norway-yv.epizy.com I only see error 404 (my own error 404 page)

Comment: You are blocking the `curl` user agent and have some sort of javascript required test to access the site so it makes it a bit hard to test.  But I can test using curl by faking the user-agent and copying my cookie from Firefox.  Testing from the command line using curl is usually the best way to ensure that you are not seeing cached content.  (Otherwise you have to clear your browser cache between each test.)

Comment: `curl -b __test=2d6e63e69ed177a52381f6adf7e80302 -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0' http://norway-yv.epizy.com/ --head` shows `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and removing the `--head` from the command shows `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=website/home.html">`

Comment: I also see that you have google-site-verification installed, but your user agent and javascript checks are going to make your site 100% inaccessible to search engine bots.  If you want to verify your site with Google and get SEO traffic, you need to remove whatever is causing those checks.

Comment: Ah, now I see. That explains a lot. It is installed by InfinityFree, so I cannot change any part of the blocking. @StephenOstermiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not working because you are missing the `<base>` tag in your `<head>`.
The base tag defines the base URL, from where relative URLS are redirected.

[For more](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: But /website works (norway-yv.epizy.com/website)

Comment: and it used to work before I changed some stuff

Comment: @norway-yv what stuff did you change?

Comment: I put everything that is part of the main website into the folder "website", so that I could upload the entire thing at once